# Can I rename a version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I like every here and there testing an older version of Minecraft, from the "old alpha" versions to the newest ones. But a while ago I let my older relative play, and after that I found a version labeled "1.**8**.10" in the profile editor in the launcher. 1.8.10! That doesn't exist! So I decedied to launch Minecraft on the version.
It's similar to the normal 1.8, just has buttons named "Metro" and "donate" in the main menu. That means I'm running the Metro hacked client!

But what I don't understand is why it's named "1.8.10"? **Is it possible to rename versions? If yes, how?**

Asking my relative is not a solution, sadly.

Comment: This version is embedded in the code. Through the code you can change it. or specifically GuiMainMenu(wc.class)

Comment: what does ps mean?

Comment: @Fennekin Post Scriptum - means "written after". "Postscript can be anything from a word, sentence, to many paragraphs."

Comment: @Fennekin It's like adding a sidenote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, I'm gonna change "1.9" to "1.99" (You can use alphanumeric characters)

First open Minecraft's data directory.

If you don't know how to do this, this screenshot will help you.
[image]

Then navigate to the folder named "versions".

To rename you'll have to change four things:

First find the folder "1.9" and rename it to "1.99" (without quotes)

Then open it. You'll see to files: "1.9.jar" and "1.9.json"

Rename them to "1.99.jar" and "1.99.json" (again, without quotes)

The last thing: open "1.99.json" with a text editor.

Find this:

[image]

Change the 1.9 in the second line with 1.99

It'll be something like this:

```
"id": "1.99",
```

Save that file, and reopen MC launcher.

Press "Add Profile" and in the "Use Version" box, you'll find 1.99
(or whatever you named the files)

Warning: You can't to rename them differently.
For example if you named the foler "ABC" you can't name the JAR "XYZ".jar